# PHP shell_exec() terminate process

Tags: php, process, kill, shell-exec, terminate

Whenever I execute command via shell_exec() in PHP it automatically starts new process. Does PHP automatically terminate that process when the command is executed?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean? the exec'd process will run until it exits and returns to php. at that point the system will terminate the process anyways. once you call exec() (or any of the related functions), php is essentially suspended and out of the picture.

Answer (score 1):

Once the commands have completed their execution PHP will automatically terminate the new process he launched and your script will continue (it can continue when the exec() commands are running but you need to redirect the output to a file)